# Is there a way to combine several variables (`set`) from different CMakelist together?

Tags: cmake

I have a project containing multiple folders and files. I want to build them all on the top-level but to keep everything clean, I had a CMakeLists.txt in every folder.

Structure looks like this:

```
home_folder
├── CMakeLists.txt (home)
├── folder_a
|       └── CMakeLists.txt (a)
└── folder_b
        └── CMakeLists.txt (b)
```

In CMakeLists.txt (a) and CMakeLists.txt (b) there are the commands`set(code_a_sources a.h .....)` and `set(code_b_sources b.h .....)`, respectively.

Is there a way to combine `code_a_sources` and `code_b_sources` into a new `all_sources` variable in CMakeLists.txt (home)?

Such as in CMakeLists.txt (home):

```
set(code_all_sources 
    ${code_a_sources} ${code_b_sources}
)
```

This doesn't work for me. I have to add all the files in CMakelists.txt (home).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMake, each new directory traversed by the CMakeLists.txt files creates a new scope. You can use [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) with `CACHE INTERNAL` to make your CMake variables visible across the different scopes.

In CMakeLists.txt (a):

```
set(code_a_sources
    a.h
    ...
    CACHE INTERNAL "Sources for folder a."
)
```

In CMakeLists.txt (b):

```
set(code_b_sources
    b.h
    ...
    CACHE INTERNAL "Sources for folder b."
)
```

In CMakeLists.txt (home):

```
set(code_all_sources 
    ${code_a_sources} ${code_b_sources}
)
```