# How to add multiple directories as Doxygen INPUT using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, python-sphinx, doxygen

I am trying to use `Doxygen` for my CPP project using `CMake` while my header files are located in different directories. Finally, the output of `Doxygen` will be used by `Sphinx`. I am motivated by this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clear-functional-c-documentation-with-sphinx-breathe-doxygen-cmake/).

My project structure is as follows:

```
.
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- doc
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- Doxyfile
|-- dir_1
|   |-- sub_dir_a
|   `-- sub_dir_b
|-- dir_2
|   |-- files_1.h
|   |-- files_2.h
```

The `INPUT` flag of `Doxyfile` is as like as follows. Which is also used by `Sphinx`.

```
INPUT                  = "@DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR@"
```

A snippet of the CMake file(`doc/CMakeLists.txt`) which holds information for Doxygen is as follows:

```
find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED)

get_target_property(ABC ABC_Lib INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJ_FILES
    ${ABC}/*.h)

set(DIR_1
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_1
    CACHE INTERNAL "Dir for folder dir_1 files"
)

set(DIR_2
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_2
    CACHE INTERNAL "Dir for folder dir_2 files"
)

set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR "${DIR_1}" "${DIR_2}") # here I want to add multiple directories(eg: dir_1, dir_2)
```

But it is not compiling successfully, and I know that `DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR` this one is not getting the path correctly. it is getting the path like that

```
project_dir/dir_1/project_dir/dir_2
```

My approach:

1. Initially I have set only with 1 directory to check my settings are OK or not(`set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR "${DIR_1}")`) and it has worked.
2. Later I have tried to add multiple directories and gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855289/how-to-set-up-doxygen-and-cmake-for-builds-that-generate-headerfiles-during-the), [this one to check how set a variable using two different directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587445/is-there-a-way-to-combine-several-variables-set-from-different-cmakelist-tog)

But both processes are failed.

##### Some points to be noted

1. I believe the `set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR ${DIR_1})` command replaces the `INPUT` tag of the `Doxyfile` with the path `DIR_1`. Am I wrong here?
2. I have set `RECURSIVE = YES` in `Doxyfile`.
3. I have a limitation to setting the `INPUT` TAG with `multiple directories` directly in the `Doxyfile`.
4. I have also tried with `set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})` while it has got all header file information to document but certainly it is not a good solution as it recursively visits all directories which cause a system overhead.

Any workaround to solve the issue?

Comment: Where have you found `DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR` at all? I can't find it in documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html `set(DIR_2 CACHE`  It's odd - why are these cache variables?

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated the post. Forgot to link the usage of the `Sphinx` and `INPUT` tag of the `Doxyfile`. Also tagged the [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clear-functional-c-documentation-with-sphinx-breathe-doxygen-cmake/) from where I am motivated

Comment: Because there are `;` in lists. Maybe you want `set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR "${DIR_1} ${DIR_2}")`, but I think you should do `doxygen_add_docs` anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you please give an example of that syntax?

Comment: It's in the documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html `set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_HTML NO)
set(DOXYGEN_GENERATE_MAN YES)

doxygen_add_docs(
    doxygen
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generate man pages"
)
`. (But I have no idea about sphinx, so maybe your approuch is required, no idea what your approuch is anyway)

Comment: I have to replace the `INPUT                  = "@DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR@"` with `Doxygen` too I guess. As at first Doxygen have to be built then Sphinx will come. by the way, I have added your suggestion. After this should I write `set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR ${doxygen})`?

What I have added is : 

```
doxygen_add_docs(
    doxygen
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_1
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir_2
    COMMENT "Generate man pages"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same guide with the following changes:

Doygen.in

```
INPUT = @DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR@ # No Quotes
```

Note that the comment in the guide says the `configure_files` command is replacing the variable inside the `@@`. As the guide is written, the INPUT variable gets written as `INPUT = "/path/to/project/dir1 /path/to/project/dir2"`, which because of the quotes, Doxygen notes as an error when you try to build.

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(DOXYGEN_DIRS
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir1
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir2
  /path/to/other/dir
)
string(REPLACE ";" " " DOXYGEN_DIRS_STR "${DOXYGEN_DIRS})  
set(DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR ${DOXYGEN_DIRS_STR})
```

This allows you to set all your Doxygen source directories, then using the string command, replace all the semicolon delimiters with spaces, and finally sets the space delimited string to `DOXYGEN_INPUT_DIR` which will get written to `DOXYGEN.in` as a single line with no quotes with the `configure_files` command.